# Question about evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1}$ (detail)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

There is a solution: 
[Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515118/evaluating-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n3n1)

But my question is why $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-x)^{3n} = \frac{1}{1 + x^{3}} $.
Isn't it work only for $ |(-x)^3|< 1 $ ?

Comment: The integration there is being carried for $\;|x|<1\;$ , precisely...

Comment: But x = -1, so |x| = 1 or am I missing something? @DonAntonio

Comment: Why do you think $\;x=-1\;$ ?

Comment: Power series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{a_n}{x^n}$ so in $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{3n+1}$ $\\ x = -1$

Comment: First of all, no: that is false...but **even if it was true**, how this would imply $\;x=-1\;$ ??

Comment: $x=1$ (not $x=-1$) was used as the integration limit.

Comment: Yes, $x = 1$ when $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-x)^{3n}$, but it could be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x)^{3n}$ with $x = -1$ too. Whatever, in both cases it isn't $|x| < 1$, so why we use equation for geometric series.

Comment: Because the value of the integrated function at a single point (in this case at the integration limit) plays NO role. You can set it to arbitrary value and it will not change the value of the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the question is for this equation:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-x)^{3n}\,dx =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^3}
$$
The two integrands agree **almost everywhere**, so the integrals are equal.    The only exception is (as noted) the value $x=1$.

(That is the Lebesgue version of the answer.  There is also a Riemann version, where we (potintially) consider the left-hand integral to be improper at the endpoint $x=1$.)